# What is the difference between phonon-infrared scattering and molecular-infrared scattering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, solid-state-physics

Are the both process same?,if not how do they differ in their mechanism,selection rules.

Comment: Are they the 'same' in what sense? Both are an interaction between a photon and matter, and coupling of an EM wave with an EM-active elastic deformation of the matter. But, a molecule is not a crystalline solid, so how one describes the them are different.

Comment: Okay,can these process exist simultaneously?,One more help,can you link me an pdf about the theory of both processes

Answer (score -2):

First, you are talking about optical phonons, that are, out of phase movements of the atoms in the lattice, one atom to the left and one (its neighbour) to the right. This occurs if the lattice basis consists of two or more atoms. They are called optical, because, in ionic crystals, they are excited by infrared radiation.

On the other hand, molecular infrared scattering is a type of inelastic scattering. it is a common misconception, where people think materials are heated up because of only absorption of EM waves. The truth is, heating up happens mostly because of inelastic scattering of infrared wavelength photons. The molecules of the material gain vibrational energies from the photons.

To answer your question, the two scattering processes are not the same.

Phonon infrared scattering is in your case with crystal lattice structured materials, that have phonons (out of phase movements in the lattice), and these scatter off infrared wavelength photons.

Molecular infrared scattering (Raman scattering) happens, when a material is heated up because the photons are inelastically scattered off the molecules, and the molecules gain vibrational (heat up) energy. In this case the molecules in the material do not have out of phase movements.

Comment: This is basically wrong. Vibrational excitations in molecules are [essentially the same thing as phonons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/184262/8563); the only difference between the two is one of degree in the size of the system.

Comment: I am asking about the elastic molecular infrared scattering,not raman. does phonon-infrared scattering occur at large scale macroscopic bodies like wood,wall if they have any ionic crystal lattice in the form of impurities

Comment: @lamme wood does not have phonons, since phonons are present in crystals like sodium chloride. Optical phonons have a non-zero frequency at the Brillouin zone center and show no dispersion near that long wavelength limit. This is because they correspond to a mode of vibration where positive and negative ions at adjacent lattice sites swing against each other, creating a time-varying electrical dipole moment. Optical phonons that interact in this way with light are called infrared active.